# golang format data to JSON format in one pass

Tags: json, regex, go, formatting, string-formatting

My original data format:

```
id=1, name=peter, age=12
```

I converted it to JSON string:

```
{"id" : "1", "name" : "peter", "age" : "12"}
```

I use the following golang statement to do the conversion:

```
Regex, err = regexp.Compile(`([^,\s]*)=([^,\s]*)`)  
JSON := fmt.Sprintf("{%s}", Regex.ReplaceAllString(inp, `"$1" : "$2"`))
```

`inp` is the variable that holds the original data format.

However, now I get a new format:

```
id=1 name=peter age=12
```

and I also want to convert to JSON string using similar method that I used above, i.e., use regex to do a one pass formatting.

```
{"id"="1", "name"="peter", "age"="12"}
```

How can I achieve that?

UPDATE: One additional requirement. if the input format is

```
id=1, name=peter, age="12"
```

I need to get rid of the "" to be or escape \" so I can process in the next step. The double quote can appear at the beginning and the end of any value field.

Comment: Your JSON strings are not valid... do you mean `{"id":"1", "name":"peter", "age":"12"}` ?

Comment: @JohnWeldon, thank you for catching. Updated!

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to the question: The easy part is serialising to JSON, Go has [standard library](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) methods for doing that.  I would use that library rather than trying to encode the JSON myself.

The slightly trickier part of your question is parsing the input into a struct or map that can be easily serialised out, and making it flexible enough to accept different input formats.

I would do it with a general interface for converting text to a struct or map, and then implementing the interface for parsing each new input type.

Sample code: (You can run it [here](https://play.golang.org/p/LgivXSKUmE))

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

// parseFn describes the function for converting input into a map.
// This could be a struct or something else if the format is well known.
// In real code this would return map[string]interface{}, but for this
// demo I'm just using string
type parseFn func(string) (map[string]string, error)

// parseFormat1 is for fields separated by commas
func parseFormat1(in string) (map[string]string, error) {
    data := map[string]string{}
    fields := strings.Split(in, ",")
    for _, field := range fields {
        pair := strings.Split(field, "=")
        if len(pair) != 2 {
            return nil, errors.New("invalid input")
        }
        data[strings.Trim(pair[0], ` "`)] = strings.Trim(pair[1], ` "`)
    }
    return data, nil
}

// parseFormat2 is for lines with no commas
func parseFormat2(in string) (map[string]string, error) {
    data := map[string]string{}
    fields := strings.Split(in, " ")
    for _, field := range fields {
        pair := strings.Split(field, "=")
        if len(pair) != 2 {
            return nil, errors.New("invalid input")
        }
        data[strings.Trim(pair[0], ` "`)] = strings.Trim(pair[1], ` "`)
    }
    return data, nil
}

// nullFormat is what we fall back on when we just don't know
func nullFormat(in string) (map[string]string, error) { return nil, errors.New("invalid format") }

// classify just tries to guess the parser to use for the input
func classify(in string) parseFn {
    switch {
    case strings.Count(in, ", ") > 1:
        return parseFormat1
    case strings.Count(in, " ") > 1:
        return parseFormat2
    default:
        return nullFormat
    }
}

func main() {
    testCases := []string{
        `id=1, name=peter, age=12`,
        `id=1, name=peter, age="12"`,
        `id=1 name=peter age=12`,
        `id=1;name=peter;age="12"`,
    }

    for ix, tc := range testCases {
        pfn := classify(tc)
        d, err := pfn(tc)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("\nerror parsing on line %d: %v\n", ix, err)
            continue
        }
        b, err := json.Marshal(d)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("\nerror marshaling on line %d: %v\n", ix, err)
            continue
        }
        fmt.Printf("\nSuccess on line %d:\n INPUT: %s\nOUTPUT: %s\n", ix, tc, string(b))
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me which library achieves this? also, some sample code please.

Comment: also does it handles the case when the value field have special characters such as "

Comment: Yeah, your real issue is parsing the input formats.  I'll provide some sample code, but you'll have to figure out exactly how to do the parsing of inputs.

Comment: There is some sample code... just ideas to get you started, you'll need to adapt to your needs.